# Unable to find a cron file

Tags: cron

I have to migrate a server to a new cloud provider. In doing so I need to copy all the LAMP code to new virtual machine. I did all that. However, on the old server one cron job runs which does something. I'm unable to find the cron file and migrate it to new server. The output of:

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

is

```
Nov  5 19:00:01 frroleapi CRON[22975]: (root) CMD (php /var/www/api/scheduler.php)
Nov  5 19:05:01 frroleapi CRON[23189]: (root) CMD (php /var/www/api/scheduler3.php)
Nov  5 19:05:01 frroleapi CRON[23190]: (root) CMD (php /var/www/api/scheduler.php)
Nov  5 19:09:01 frroleapi CRON[23382]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) -delete)
```

The last cronjob is a file `php5` in `/etc/cron.d`. However, I'm unable to find the cron files for earlier entries.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to open the list of scheduled cron events with the crontab command. This should also show you what files run during the cron and where they are located:

```
crontab -l
```

You can then add these cron entries to the new server using crontab with the edit parameter, like this:

```
crontab -e
```

For more information, see also: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5

This tutorial may also be helpful for understanding cron and crontab: http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/